# AngularJS Push New Data into Specific JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've got a JSON output that looks like this:

```
[{"id":"121","title":"Blog Title","content":"Blog content"}, "comments":[{"id":"12","content":"This is the comment."}]]
```

I'm retrieving the array through a controller in Angular:

```
app.controller('BlogController', function($scope, $http) {
    var blog = this;
    blog.posts = [];

    $http.get('/process/getPost.php').success(function (data) {
        blog.posts=data;
    });

    $scope.submitComment = function() {

        blog.posts.concat($scope.formData);

        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/process/insertComment.php',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.formData.comment="";
        });
    };
})
```

Then displaying the information in my index.html file:

```
<div ng-controller="BlogController as blog" ng-cloak class='ng-cloak'>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div>{{post.title}}</div>
        <div>{{post.content}}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
        {{comment.content}}
    </div>
    <form name="commentform" ng-init="formData.id=post.id" novalidate>
        <textarea ng-model="formData.comment" name="comment" required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="commentform.$invalid" value="Submit" ng-click="submitComment()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Everything works as it should but I've been trying to have the submitComment() update comment.content inside JSON array where the blog id equals post.id and where the comment id equals comment.id.

I've tried doing blog.post.comment.push($scope.formData) but that didn't work.  Any idea why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: That's not valid JSON :S

Comment: Can you clearify the question ?

Comment: hi as posts is array of post you need to be more specific to which one post do you want to add comment and as @PixnBits mention your JSON is not valid as well

Comment: Can you explain why it's not valid?

Comment: paste it into http://pro.jsonlint.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might help you http://jsbin.com/fatote/2/edit?html,js,output

```
  $scope.submitComment = function(post) {



    $http.post('/process/insertComment.php', post.formData)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.formData.comment="";
        }, function(){

          alert("Can't post");

        }).then(function(){

      //finally as we know that post would work in that case
      //find last comment id
          var newCommentId = post.comments[post.comments.length-1].id +1;
      //create new comment obj
      var newComment = {
          id:newCommentId,
          content:post.formData.comment
            };
      //push comment in comments array
       post.comments.push(newComment);

      //clean form
       post.formData.comment="";


    });


    };
```

Comment: This led me to my answer.  I ended up needing to pass formData into submitComment() then adding formData to the variable function and using it to clear the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `blog.posts.concat($scope.formData);` isn't being assigned anywhere. Note that `.concat` is different from `.sort` in that you're creating a *new* array.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat): "The `concat()` method returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s) and/or value(s)."

Try changing your line to `blog.posts = blog.posts.concat($scope.formData);`

**edit:**

I'm guessing at your data format, more likely the change needed is:

```
var post = blog.posts[blogPostId]; // you'll need to determine blogPostId
post.comments = post.comments.concat($scope.formData);
```